# searching in html/txt without loading it into program

Tags: html, delphi, pascal

I need to find a way how to look into files that are not loaded into any component or stringlist in my program. Is it possible to work lets say like `copy(somefile.html, 1, 100)`? I have a file of messages from facebook and I want to do program that can for example count how many msgs I have with some person but this kind of thing I can do on my own, my only problem is to find a way how to work with this file. It will probably be stringlist? but I am not sure.

Comment: No, you must load the file content into memory before you can then work with it. Look at `TStringList.LoadFromFile()`, `TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile()`, `System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllBytes()`, etc.  Or use a memory mapping via `CreateFile()`/`CreateFileMapping()`/`MapViewOfFile()`.

Comment: Why? Is this an xy question, you have a problem x and think that y will solve it, but you don't know how to do y.

Comment: I dunno if there's other way to do it. You can use `WebBrowser` or the other examples like @RemyLebeau said.

Comment: @Remy: or load *parts* into memory, e.g. line by line or buffer by buffer. It does not have to be the entire file content at once.

Comment: I've read your edited question, but I still don't understand why you do not want to load the file into your own program. Are you afraid that you might destroy the file or what is it?

Comment: Because the file is to big and every component lags the program when I try to load the data.

Comment: then try buffered reading, there is some good questions about that in here

Comment: Facebook has API, use that (do not download the content and process it by yourself, it's an extra work). To your specific question as I interpret it (_How to process HTML file (possibly just the Facebook message list)?_), look for HTML parser. But definitely prefer the FB API if it's FB specific stuff.